# InvalidOperationException on webservice call with C# client and Java server side

Tags: c#, java, web-services

My issues is similar to [C# error executing soap client method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336834/c-sharp-error-executing-soap-client-method) but not exact.  I want to pose a different question.  On the Java server side I have a webservice with several methods.  Here are 2 examples (mostly want to show the annotations here):

```
@WebResult(name = "result")
@WebMethod 
public TheResult method1(string x, string y) 
throws Exception
{
         TheResult result = new TheResult();
         // continue with code, not important
         return result;
      }
@WebResult(name = "result")
@WebMethod 
public Boolean method2(int x, string y) 
throws Exception
{
         Boolean result = new TheResult();
         // continue with code, not important
         return result;
      }
```

There are more methods and they all use @WebResult(name = "result").  The Java side was written by another developer long ago and I don't have an option to change this.  I am getting an InvalidOperationException, Message=There was an error reflecting 'result'.  The inner exception is the same but the messag is : The top XML element 'result' from namespace '' references distinct types...[details here left out purposely] Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.  As you can tell from my post so far I have zero'd in on the fact that the previous developer used 'result' for all web methods.  This seems to be the problem and if I change the server code and recompile for testing purposes I can avoid the exception (again this is not an option).

I am using VS2012 for the client and I was able to pull in the Java webservice with little effort.  Code was generated as expected.  The exception occurs when I attempt to make a call to method1(bla, bla).  How can I solve this on the client side using client side techniques only?

Comment: Small clarification, when I say "if I change the server code", I'm talking about randomly assigning each @WebResult to :  result1, result2, result3, result4 and so on